# Hint user to flip device when taking a Picture

Tags: android, camera

In a part of an app I'm building the user should take an image / pick one from the gallery. The thing is, the image must be oriented horizontally. I would like to show the user a hint on-screen to flip his device if he is holding it in portarit, [like google is doing in their new camera app](http://gizmodo.com/yes-googles-new-camera-app-yells-people-for-taking-ver-1564624973) (only in video mode, though)

Is it possible to do this without creating my own camera activity? I'm currently using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent to open the default camera.

Comment: You could make an AlertDialog appear. With only an OK button which dismisses it. And show your text in there.

Comment: All native camera apps are different per device, so if you're using the native camera app which you are because you are using the intent then I don't think it's viable. Sorry :c

Comment: Ok, thanks. @Frank N. Stein, can you elaborate ? Can I display the AlertDialog, even if the user is currently is in another app? I don't think its possible :/

Comment: You can display just a Toast message. An AlertDialog will annoy after two times.

Comment: @greenapps It doesn't work. onConfigurationChanged doesn't get called when the user flips the phone and is in another application. The only ways I can think of is request the user to first flip the phone and then send him to the camera (but then he could just flip back), or building my own camera activity, which is probably what I'm going to have to do.

Comment: Well i did not talk about configuration changes. You did not ask the first replyer where/when to show the dialog. Saw that an AlertDialog was proposed. So i suggested a Toast. That was all. I now reread your post and dont know the solution but suggest you display a toast the moment the user starts the camera. The code can determine the orientation of the device at that moment. So you can display a relevant toast.

Comment: `pick one from the gallery` ? Only portrait?

Comment: No, both gallery & camera should be horizontal.Picking from the gallery is easy because I could just tell the user the picture isn't good. But when capturing an image I don't want to bother him going back and forth between the camera and the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I've built my own camera application which detects rotation and hints the user to rotate the device if it's in portrait mode.